# How do I increase the font size in Activity Monitor?

Tags: font, activity-monitor

I've tried `cmd+` and `cmd-`, and I've looked through all the menus.

I'm aware of "accessibility zoom" and it is not an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity Monitor does not provide any method of adjusting the font size.
You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html